# Python OS.System with variables and quotes

Tags: python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

readLine = open('desktops.txt','r')

for line in readLine:
       machineName = line
       query = os.system(r'wmic -U corp.fakedomain.com/domainusername%password //'+machineName+ '"Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = True"|grep "500|"|cut -d "\\" -f 2|cut -d "|" -f1')
```

Getting.....

"Example: wmic -U [domain/]adminuser%password //host "select * from Win32_ComputerSystem"
sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string"

If i replace the \\machineName variable with a real IP 192.168.1.100 it works fine.

Comment: Try replacing `line` with `line.strip()`: `machineName = line.strip()`

Comment: That stopped the "Example: wmic -U [domain/]adminuser%password //host "select * from Win32_ComputerSystem" sh from showing up but still getting Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string"